# Long running Rails migration steps don't seem to finish

Tags: mysql, rake, rails-migrations

I've got some rake migrations set up. One of the tables I'm modifying has several hundred thousand rows, with data length of 1,962,754,048 bytes (essentially, a 2GB table). This is an InnoDB table. I'm adding a couple of columns to the table via rake.

Unfortunately, the `change_table` step never "finishes". The query running on the backend is complete, but the rake step never seems to advance.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be related to an index problem.

I would try breaking your migrations down into:

```
Drop all indexes (you can do this in mysql if you want, might be easier).

Add the new columns

Add all required indexes back (If you did this in mysql, do that again, if you dropped the indexes through migrations, add them back thru migrations).
```

It might help and/or might help pinpoint where the issue is.